# Change permissions symbolic link Mac OS

Tags: macos, chmod

How do you change the permissions of a system link on Mac OS ?

I tried `chmod -h 755 mylink` using iTerm2 with zsh, but it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work? What happened? What's `ls -l mylink` before and after `chmod`.

Comment: The before and after look exactly the same, the link was not modified...
`lrwxrwxrwx  1 varnaud  july  6 Jul 12 09:35 mylink -> myfile`

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. Here's what I get.
$ zsh<br>
> $ touch myfile
> $ ln -s myfile mylink
> $ ls -l myfile mylink
>  -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Jul 12 17:34 myfile
>  lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  6 Jul 12 17:35 mylink -> myfile
>  $ chmod -h 0777 mylink
>  $ ls -l myfile mylink 
>  -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Jul 12 17:34 myfile
>  lrwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  6 Jul 12 17:35 mylink -> myfile

Comment: Well, I made a mess. The short of it is that it worked here in zsh.

Comment: The question mentions Mac OS, but your tag is Linux.  Are there details you're leaving out or was this just the wrong tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I went totally the wrong direction with this problem, allow me to restate the issue involved. Let's look at why symbolic link permissions are meaningless, so changing them or not isn't useful.

I cannot reproduce the problem. On [some systems](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/why-chmod-cannot-change-symbolic-link-permission-102012/), symlink permissions can't be changed at all. My experience is that Mac OS El Capitan does change symlink permissions in most situations, but the new permissions have no effect.

Conceptually, a change to the permissions of a symlink must have no effect. If accessing a file was as easy as creating a symlink and then changing the permissions of the symlink, no file would be secure.

I found this disclaimer in `man 7 symlink`:

> The flags, access permissions, owner/group and modification time of an existing symbolic link can be changed by means of [system calls]. Of these, only the flags are used by the system; ***the access permissions and ownership are ignored***.

Here's an extreme example.

```
$ touch myfile
$ ln -s myfile mylink
$ ls -l myfile mylink
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Jul 13 14:42 myfile
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  6 Jul 13 14:43 mylink -> myfile
$ chmod -h 000 mylink
$ ls -l myfile mylink
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Jul 13 14:42 myfile
ls: mylink: Permission denied
l---------  1 user  staff  6 Jul 13 14:43 mylink
$ echo 'Hello, world!' > mylink
$ cat mylink
Hello, world!
$ ls -l myfile
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  14 Jul 13 14:43 myfile
```

The symlink has no permissions, but `echo` and `cat` follow `mylink` to `myfile`. `echo` writes to `myfile` and `cat` reads it, ignoring the symlink permissions. NB: The symlink permissions blocked `ls` from showing the target of the symlink, but utilities still follow the symlink. Conversely,

```
$ chmod 000 myfile
$ chmod -h 777 mylink
$ ls -l myfile mylink
----------  1 user  staff  14 Jul 13 14:43 myfile
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff   6 Jul 13 14:43 mylink -> myfile
$ cat mylink
cat: mylink: Permission denied
```

Rhetorically, isn't this how it has to be?

References (some specific to Mac OS and El Capitan):

- `man 7 symlink`
- ACL MANIPULATION OPTIONS section of `man chmod`
- `man chflags`